# Jquery fancy box not working on div

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have html source as

```
<div class="widget-container">
    <ul class="lazyest_random_list">
        <li class="lazyest_random" id="random_0" style="">
            <div class="lg_thumb">
                <div class="lg_thumb_image">
                    <a id="lg_thumb_onclick_pooja-gupta-hot-2-jpg_4763" href="http://test.com/20%282%29.jpg" class="thickbox" rel="pooja-gupta-hot" ">
                        <img class="thumb" src="http://test.com/thumb/20%282%29.jpg" ">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="lazyest_random" id="random_1" style="">
            <div class="lg_thumb">
                <div class="lg_thumb_image">
                    <a id="lg_thumb_onclick_andria-dsouza6-jpg_4763" href="http://test.com%286%29.jpg" class="thickbox" rel="andria-dsouza" ">
                        <img class="thumb" src="http://test.com/thumb/%286%29.jpg" ">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I am trying to apply jquery fancybox and that is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */
    $("#widget-container .a").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });
});
```

Any inputs to work this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`widget-container` is the class of your container, not the id. Also, as far as I can see, there are no elements within there with the class name `a`, I think you mean to target the **tagname** `a`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */
    $(".widget-container a").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like this works for sample image. But not for the exact item. I can see the images are loaded after the above function fired. Any way to avoid this problem.

Comment: Are you asking how you can [preload an image?](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)

Comment: The question is this code is not working if the images are lazy loaded, any way to overcome this issue?